# Numeric Linear Interpolation on Delphi

Tags: r, delphi, delphi-xe5, linear-interpolation

I need to make a simple numeric linear interpolation in Delphi, was thinking of implementing a function, but then thought better and I think that should already be some library. I found nothing on google.

My problem is simple, I have a dataset with X and Y data, and other new dataset X data (Xb) that will be the basis for finding new Y data (Yin) interpolated.

In R, for example, have a function `approx` that accomplishes this easily. This function also allows Xb length is of any size.

```
Yin <- approx (X, Y, Xb, method = "linear")$y
```

There is some statistical library to do this in Delphi? Or continue to write my function (based on `approx`)?

Comment: Something like GDI+? Which Delphi version are you using? That's an important tag for questions about something "in Delphi" because 2009+ has GDI+ built-in. If under 2009, you can still find other third-party libraries, or wrap the API yourself.

Comment: Is GDI+ a graphic library to C++/C#? I want to do something more simple, a numeric linear interpolation, I will edit the question.

Comment: GDI+ is a Windows API. So it can be used from any language that compiles to Windows. http://www.bilsen.com/gdiplus/index.shtml

Comment: @Jerry GDI+ is a graphics library. Linear interpolation is a mathematical algorithm.

Comment: @David I apparently misinterpreted it, thinking it was related to linear drawing. I need to pay better attention.

Comment: Thinking better my question is off-topic, sorry for that. Off-topic's questions must be deleted?

Comment: @Artur It's fine. The question might get deleted by mods. Probably not. You've got a nice answer though. No harm here. Thanks for thinking about this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linear interpolation of 1D-data is very simple:

- Find such index in X-array, that `X[i] <= Xb < X[i+1]`

(binary search for case of random access, linear search for case of step-by step Xb changing)

- Calculate

  ```
  Yb = Y[i] + (Y[i+1] - Y[i]) * (Xb - X[i]) / (X[i+1] - X[i])
  ```

Comment: this is the way that I do. Thinking better my question may be off-topic, but thanks for help.